Can Cleric take Champion's Devotion Spell opposing their Divine Font?
Cleric's Divine Font ability states:

Through your deity's blessing, you gain additional spells that channel either the life force called vitality or its counterforce, the void. When you prepare your spells each day, you can prepare additional heal or harm spells, depending on your deity. The divine font spell your deity provides is listed in the Divine Font entry for your deity; if both are listed, you can choose between heal or harm. Once you choose, you can't change your choice short of divine intervention

Champion's Devotion Spells ability says:

Your deity’s power grants you special divine spells called devotion spells, which are a type of focus spell. Choose one of the spells, either shields of the spirit or a spell based on your deity’s divine font (lay on hands if your deity allows heal, touch of the
void if your deity allows harm).

Question: If a Cleric of a god that allows both Heal and Harm would take a Champion archetype and gain access to Champion's Devotion Spells - can they take spell that won't match their chosen Divine Font? (I.e. Can Cleric of Abadar, who took Healing as Divine Font, take Touch of the Void devotion spell? Or Harmful Cleric of Abadar take Lay on Hands?) RAW, it seems that it's possible, but it doesn't feel right logically. Was there any official clarification that I couldn't find on my own or some rules that I've missed?

Yes
There is nothing preventing you from choosing opposites (i.e. pairing Touch of the Void with Healing Divine Font, or Lay on Hands with Harming Divine Font). You could even take Shields of the Spirit. Gods that allow both harm and heal often have some sort of duality to their nature - this was often representing pre-remaster as them being one of the neutral alignments (Abadar was lawful neutral). For some deities, like Nethys, taking opposites might even make more sense than taking the same. Abadar, focused on law, order, and commerce, needs executioners just as much as he needs healers:

Aristocrats, city guards, merchants, and those working in legal practice or who have the well-being of their community [e.g. healing] on their mind are common worshippers of the god of cities, along with dwarves in general. Abadaran priests living in cities often serve as judges, lawyers, and clerks, while those who live on the frontier work as roving magistrates, acting as judge, jury, and executioners [e.g. harming] in the name of order.

Even pre-remaster this was possible, via a deity like Ragathiel or Dammerich allowing you to take a harmful font while having a good alignment (which would get you lay on hands), or the Green Mother or Ragadahn allowing the reverse.

(it is hard to prove a negative, so I definitely welcome feedback on anything I missed)
